# Change Voice in SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speechsynthesizer

I tried to change the speaker, but i dont have enlisted all installed speakers (George, Susan, Jakub) in `SpeechSynthesizer` class, on the other hand I have one, that is not installed at all (Zira).

[image]
[image]

What is happening here ? Can i somehow add specific speaker into my project (for example as .dll or something) to be not dependent on computer language/region ?

Answer (score 1):

---

**UPDATE**

As @Jimi mentioned, System.Speech and Microsoft.Speech are different and to avoid confusion, using only one of them should be the right choice.

**For System.Speech**

1. Go to Settings/Region and Language/Add Language
2. From Settings of the language, download Speech

For example **Helen** is in en_US package. So, the additional Speech should be downloaded by adding **English (United States)** language.

**For Microsoft.Speech**

1. Download a speech from the link below
2. Add a reference to the
       Microsoft.Speech DLL in the project

---

Microsoft Speech Recognition and Text-to-Speech engine data files can be downloaded from the link below;

**Speech Recognition and Text-to-Speech Engines for Microsoft supported Languages** https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224

For further information:
**Microsoft Speech Programming Guide**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh378466(v%3doffice.14)

**SpeechSynthesizer.SelectVoice Method**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/dd167624(v%3Doffice.14)

**System.Speech.Synthesis Namespace**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thank you, i installed Helen (MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_Helen.msi), because Jakub is missing in the "TTS MSI packages" list, but still no luck. Helen is also missing in the InstalledVoices list after installation :/ Also i dont see Helen in speech settings, something is strange here.

Comment: These are two completely different assemblies and technologies: `Microsoft.Speech` and `System.Speech`. The OP is using the latter.